# Foreach loop and multidimensional array

Tags: php

Here is a sample of the multidimensional array being outputted.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 34
            [name] => ACS Consultants
            [slug] => acs-consultants
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 34
            [taxonomy] => ad_cat
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [cat_ID] => 34
            [category_count] => 0
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => ACS Consultants
            [category_nicename] => acs-consultants
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 18
            [name] => Business Development
            [slug] => business-development
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 18
            [taxonomy] => ad_cat
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [cat_ID] => 18
            [category_count] => 0
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Business Development
            [category_nicename] => business-development
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 12
            [name] => Cash In Transit
            [slug] => cash-in-transit
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 12
            [taxonomy] => ad_cat
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [cat_ID] => 12
            [category_count] => 0
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Cash In Transit
            [category_nicename] => cash-in-transit
            [category_parent] => 0
        )
)
```

What i'm trying to do is take `name` and `cat_ID` and put into a new array like this

```
$newarray['ACS Consultants']=34;
$newarray['Business Development']=18;
$newarray['Cash In Transit']=12;
```

Here is my attempt but didn't work

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );

$newarray = array();


foreach($categories as $array) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if($key=="name") {
        $term = $key;
        $newarray[$term]="";
        }

        if($key=="cat_ID") {
        $newarray[$term]=$value;
        }
    }
}
```

How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just an array of objects, you only need one loop. and you access the objects with `->`

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $newArray[$category->name] = $category->cat_ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a second foreach loop, this should do it

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($categories as $array)
{
  $newArray[$array['name']] = $array['cat_ID'];
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

outputs

```
array(3) {
  ["ACS Consultants"]=>string(2) "34"
  ["Business Development"]=>string(2) "18"
  ["Cash In Transit"]=>string(2) "12"
}
```

Although I did set `$categories` to an array of arrays for testing, so you may need to try the following if `name` and `cat_ID` are properties

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($categories as $array)
{
  $newArray[$array->name] = $array->cat_ID;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```